# Application crash at setvisibility android

Tags: java, android

I'm a new developer and I'm encountering a problem when setting the visibility of a layout that covers my UI to disable it while running a script.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;

        case R.id.action_loadfile:
            saveTellNamesArray();
            LoadFile(txtFolder, ScriptArray);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_runscript:

            disableLayout();

            stopScript = false;

            scriptThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (!scriptThread.isInterrupted() && !stopScript) {
                        runScript();
                    }
                    if (stopScript)//revisar
                        enableLayout();
                }
            });
            scriptThread.start();

            //enableLayout();
            return true;

        case R.id.action_stopscript:
            if (scriptThread != null) {
                //scriptThread.interrupt();
                stopScript = true;
            }
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the app crashes as soon as i call the enableLayout() function:

```
public void disableLayout() {
    uiBlockLayout.setVisibility(FrameLayout.VISIBLE);
    uiBlockLayout.bringToFront();
}

public void enableLayout() {
    uiBlockLayout.setVisibility(FrameLayout.GONE);
}
```

Any clues on what the problem might be?

Comment: Please, **share** the **log error**.

Comment: What Nawako says, plus the scope in which `uiBlockLayout` is assigned a value.

Comment: Thank you all, the answer given by @ρяσѕρєя K is the right one. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any clues on what the problem might be?

Yes, Issue is occurring accessing UI elements from `non UI Thread`(calling `enableLayout` method `scriptThread` Thread run method).

Use `runOnUiThread` method for accessing Views from non Ui Thread:

```
if (stopScript){
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        enableLayout();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @Mena what depends on the API level? runOnUiThread has been there since API 1

Comment: @Sombrero22 please check this answer, it will surely solve your problem. don't forget to mark as correct answer!

Comment: Thanks @ρяσѕρєяK, your answer is the right one. Never expected so fast response, so glad this site exists. Keep up the good work.  :)